# Computing average of scores for strings in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, average

How can I write a python program that takes the values for strings in a dictionary with an input of any string and dictionary in the form:

```
score("a b" , {"a":(1.2) , "b":(3.4)})
```

and returns the average of the values as a float?

Comment: And how is that string being interpreted?

Comment: what is the value of the string in the example? what have you tried?

Comment: For what exactly do you want to compute the average here?

Comment: @gnibbler --  I see.  deleted my comment then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want:

```
def score(key_str,dct):
    keys = key_str.split()
    v = sum(dct[key] for key in keys)
    return float(v)/len(keys)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less abstract answer.

```
def score(hairypeople, hair_length):
    """ Calculates the average nosehair length given a string of people's names 
    and a dictionary of the length of their nose hairs.  """ 
    list_of_hairy_people = hairypeople.split()
    number_of_hairy_people = len(list_of_hairy_people)
    sum_length_of_hairs = sum([hair_length[ew] for ew in list_of_hairy_people])
    return float(sum_length_of_hairs) / number_of_hairy_people
```